# json to xml java

Tags: java, xml, json

I want convert json to xml 
here is code

```
public class ConvertJSONtoXML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = ConvertJSONtoXML.class.getResourceAsStream("demo1.txt");

        String jsonData = IOUtils.toString(is);
        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonData);

    String xml = serializer.write((JSON) json);
        System.out.println(xml);
```

Here is demo1.txt

```
{"name":"naveed" }
```

It reads demo1.txt file and convert into xml but i m trying to pass json as string.

```
String jsonString="{\"name\":\"naveed\" }";
InputStream is = ConvertJSONtoXML.class.getResourceAsStream(jsonString);
```

but it wont work for string..

i thing `getResourceAsStream(jsonString)` doesnt work for string....
please suggest any reference

Comment: Looks like you'd have to parse an object first, and then serialize to xml. Or be the first to create cross serializer.

Comment: I think you use `getResourceAsStream` incorrectly. It is certainly impossible to pass to it JSON string: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.jsonToXml().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getResourceAsStream()` actually looks on the file system for resource identified by the input string and open an input stream for it.

You should rather use something like

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( jsonString.getBytes() );
```

Also, you should take care of using compatible charsets.